# event listener for group dragging

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I try to reproduce the [fabric's manage selection](http://fabricjs.com/manage-selection)

For that
I create a 'paint app' in which we can draw line draw rectangle and drag 
The goal is to drag and drop all the line which is inside a rectangle with the rectangle itself when the drag input is click

I store the lines coordonates in storedLines 
In mousedown:

I get the current mouse position set the isDragging flag on any shape that is under the mouse

save the current mouse position and make a loop through the storedLines to see all the lines that is inside the rectangle

```
if(that.type == "drag"){
      dragok=false;
      for(var i=0;i<storedLines.length;i++){
          var r=storedLines[i];
          if(r.x1>startX && r.x2<(mouseX + startX) && r.y1>startY &&  r.y2<(mouseY + startY)){
              // if yes, set that rects isDragging=true
              dragok=true;
              r.isDragging=true;
              ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
          }
      }
   }
```

In mousemove:

I get the current mouse position

calculate how far the mouse has moved ( distance = newMousePosition-oldMousePosition )

add the distance to the position of any shape that isDragging

save the current mouse position

redraw the scene with shapes in their new positions

but the problem is I can't make it drag and drop because even when the drop button is clicked on mouse down I continue drawing rectangle

```js
var storedLines = [];
var startX = 0;
var startY = 0;
var isDown;
var type = "line"; // current type
var dragok = false;
class CanvasState{
  // **** First some setup! ****
 constructor(canvas){
  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.type = type;
  this.width = canvas.width;
  this.height = canvas.height;
  this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var offsetX = canvas.offsetLeft;
  var offsetY = canvas.offsetTop;
  this.valid = false; // when set to false, the canvas will redraw everything
  this.shapes = [];  // the collection of things to be drawn
  this.dragging = false; // Keep track of when we are dragging
  this.selection = null;
  this.dragoffx = 0; // See mousedown and mousemove events for explanation
  this.dragoffy = 0;
  var myState = this;
  this.selectionColor = '#CC0000';
  this.selectionWidth = 2;  
  var that = this;
  

  canvas.addEventListener('selectstart', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); return false; }, false);
  // Up, down, and move are for dragging
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";

    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    isDown = true;
    startX = mouseX;
    startY = mouseY;

    // test each rect to see if lines are inside
    if(that.type == "drag"){
      dragok=false;
      for(var i=0;i<storedLines.length;i++){
          var r=storedLines[i];
          if(r.x1>startX && r.x2<(mouseX + startX) && r.y1>startY &&  r.y2<(mouseY + startY)){
              // if yes, set that rects isDragging=true
              dragok=true;
              r.isDragging=true;
              ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
          }
      }
   }
  }, true);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!isDown) return;

    myState.redrawStoredLines();

    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    if(that.type == "rect"){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(startX, startY, mouseX - startX, mouseY - startY);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
    // if we're dragging anything...
    if (that.type == "drag"){

      // tell the browser we're handling this mouse event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      // get the current mouse position
      var mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      var my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // calculate the distance the mouse has moved
      // since the last mousemove
      var dx=mx-startX;
      var dy=my-startY;

      // move each line that isDragging 
      // by the distance the mouse has moved
      // since the last mousemove
      myState.redrawStoredLines();
    }
    if(that.type == "line"){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
        ctx.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
        ctx.stroke();
    }

  }, true);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    
      canvas.style.cursor = "default";
     
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    isDown = false;
    
    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    storedLines.push({
        type: that.type,
        x1: startX,
        y1: startY,
        x2: mouseX,
        y2: mouseY
    });
    console.log(storedLines);
    myState.redrawStoredLines();
  
  }, true);

canvas.addEventListener('handleMouseOut', function(e) {
    
      e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    
    if (!isDown) return;

    isDown = false;
    
    var mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
    var mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

    storedLines.push({
        type: that.type,
        x1: startX,
        y1: startY,
        x2: mouseX,
        y2: mouseY
    });

    myState.redrawStoredLines();
  

  }, true);
  
  
}
setType(newtype){
  if ( newtype === 'line' ) {
    this.type = "line";
    
   } 
   if ( newtype === 'rect' ) {
      this.type = "rect";
     console.log('settype:' + this.type);
   }  
}

 

 redrawStoredLines() {

    
    var ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

    if (storedLines.length == 0) return;

    // redraw each stored line
    for (var i = 0; i < storedLines.length; i++) {
        if(storedLines[i].type === "line"){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y1);
            ctx.lineTo(storedLines[i].x2, storedLines[i].y2);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        if(storedLines[i].type === "rect"){
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.rect(storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y1, 
                storedLines[i].x2 - storedLines[i].x1, storedLines[i].y2 - storedLines[i].y1);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        if (storedLines[i].type === "drag"){

            
            // move each line that isDragging 
            // by the distance the mouse has moved
            // since the last mousemove
          for(var i=0;i<storedLines.length;i++){
                    var r=storedLines[i];
                  if(r.x1>startX && r.x2<(mouseX + startX) && r.y1>startY &&  r.y2<(mouseY + startY)){
                      
                        if(r.isDragging){
                            r.x+=dx;
                            r.y+=dy;
                        }
                    }

              }
      }
    }
}

}

var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name="shape"]');

function changeHandler(event) {
  
    console.log(event.srcElement.value);
    mycanvas.setType(event.srcElement.value);
   
  
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, function(radio) {
   radio.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
  
});


var mycanvas =  new CanvasState(document.getElementById('mainCanvas'));
```

```css
 

body{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 16px;
}

.container{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #505050 
}

h3{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
}

.toolbox{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;    
}

.toolbox > li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;    
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div.sliders div{
    /*margin-top: 20px;    */
    display: inline-block;
}

.in-line p{
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
}

.in-line input{
    margin: 5px;
    display: block;
}


#square{
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 48%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
}

#rgbcolor{
    font-size: 14px; 
    text-align: center;   
}

#clearbtn{
    width: 50px;
    margin-left: 48%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.canvas{    
    margin: 10px;
    position: relative;    
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    cursor: crosshair;    
}

#coords{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <h3>Drawing Shapes</h3> 
    <div>
        <ul class="toolbox">
            <li id="btns">
              <div >        
                
                <input type="radio" name="shape" id="line" value="line">Line<br>
                <input type="radio" name="shape" id="drag" value="drag">Drag<br>
                <input type="radio" name="shape" id="rect" value="rect">Rectangle<br>                
              </div>
              <div class="sliders">
                <div class="in-line">
                  <p>Red</p>
                  <p>Green</p>
                  <p>Blue</p>                  
                </div>
                <div class="in-line">
                  <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="127" name="Red" id="red" >
                  <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="127" name="Green" id="green" >
                  <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="127" name="Blue" id="blue" >
                </div>                                                
              </div>
              <div><p id="rgbcolor">RGB(127, 127, 127)</p><div id="square"></div></div>
                         
            </li>            
            <li id="cnvs">
              <div>
                <canvas id="mainCanvas" class="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>  
                <h3 id="coords">(X, Y) : (0 , 0)</h3>
              </div> 
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>                                                         
  </div>
```

Comment: When drag button is clicked, you want to select and drag lines/rectangles?

Comment: lines inside the rectangle. The idea is to use rectangle as a selection tool so every lines inside the rectangle are selected and then when the drag button is clicked the rectangle and all the line inside are drag on mousedown follow the mousemove and drop on the position of the mouseup